How do I reduce the space between a paragraph and a figure?
First of all: English is not my first language. Sorry for potential errors and not being able to be 100% clear.
I'm doing the final layout of a scientific paper, which have 2 massive figures (figures made by a framed minipage) in between 2 paragraphs. By the layout rules of the journal, I can put these images after the text, to improve the usage of the space and not have a enormous gap between the two paragraphs.
    \begin{figure}[H]
     \newcommand\x{0.5}
     \caption{Time series boxplot for each station observed in relation to the spatial distribution for pollutants (a) PM$_{10}$ and (b) TSP.}
    
      \begin{framed}
       \begin{minipage}[t]{\x\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1, bb=0 0 1024 1024, width = \textwidth, trim={0 0.8cm 0 0.9cm},clip]{author_files/PM10.pdf} 
        \captionsetup{justification=centering, font=footnotesize}
        \caption*{(a)}\label{fig:fig2a}
       \end{minipage}
    
       \begin{minipage}[t]{\x\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[bb=0 0 1024 1024, width = \textwidth, trim={0 0.8cm 0 0.9cm},clip]{author_files/PTS.pdf}   
         \captionsetup{justification=centering, font=footnotesize}
         \caption*{(b)}\label{fig:fig2b}
       \end{minipage} \\
      \end{framed}
          
    {\footnotesize Source: Elaborated by the authors (2022).}
    \end{figure}

After compiling the code, I'm left with this:

The code above was made for Figures 5 and 6. Fig. 06 is shown immediately after Fig. 5 and then the text continues with the paragraph that was separated by the Figures.
How can I move the text that is after Fig. 6 to be shown before the Fig. 5?

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

By default figures move to avoid such spac ebut you have used \begin{figure}[H] to force such space to avoid moving the figures
